# How to remove rows in a pandas data frame when cells start with a certain character?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns 0 through 21. In column 11, there is data that either starts with a letter or two asterisks “**” and then a letter. I want to delete all rows in which the value in column 11 starts with **.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I have found  ways to drop rows when a cell is a certain value but can’t find how to drop them when a cell contains a certain character.

Comment: `df[~df['column11'].str.startswith('**')]`